# Distinguishing two classes of links in the new footer

Tags: feature-request, design, footer

A new footer was announced in [a blog entry](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/27/new-stack-overflow-footer-pages-launch-today/?cb=1).
I like the new footer, but there's one aspect I find counterintuitive:
There are two types of links but there's no difference in appearance.

For example:

- If I click "Science", the footer shows me science-related SE sites. The footer changes but I stay on the same page.
- If I click "About", I'm taken to a whole new page.

These two links look exactly alike, and I can't tell what will happen if I click one of the links.
After scratching my head for a moment and looking at the URL when hovering over various links, I figured out how it works.
But it'd be better if it was easier than that.
Also, inconsistent links are irritating.

**Could the links in the last column (Technology, Life / Arts, Culture / Recreation, Science, Other) have some kind of visual clue that they are different from the rest of the footer links?**
Something that says "click to expand" and applies only to those five links would be nice.
I don't know how to solve the problem, but I think there is one.

Comment: Reported on Meta.SO: [Give a hint that navigation in footer is expandable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351359) (where this really belongs, since the new footer is an SO-only feature).

Comment: @Walt Thanks! I don't follow SO meta at all since I don't use SO. I just saw the blog and assumed it would eventually be network-wide.

Comment: This is off topic here. The new footer is only for Stack Overflow, which has its own meta site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do you know if this new appearance including the footer is intended to be for SO only? I was under the impression that it was being tested there and about to be rolled out for the whole network, but I could of course be mistaken.

Comment: The blog post does not mention such a thing. Since they still don't show any signs of shipping the new top bar to other sites, long months after changing it on SO, I assume it's in the 6-8 years range. I don't think they do this to test, they do this to make Stack Overflow appear different and have its own design, unique to the network.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - please don't jump to conclusions. The new footer will be rolled out network-wide once design is finalized for those.

Comment: @Oded once such tests took place here on Meta. SO is the new sandbox for design changes?

Comment: This is not a test.